# Example on implementing HTML5 Server Side Event in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html

I am trying to introduce HTML5 Server-Side-Event to my Rails 3.2 project. I did some search at Google.com, but most of the examples are using php. There's only one example on Rails that is using `Goliath`, and I am not using that.

I am using `Thin` in my development and deploying with `passenger`. I think it's valid for doing text streaming for SSE. Is there any examples on Rails 3.2 for reference?

Comment: Is this the only one example you found: http://www.igvita.com/2011/08/26/server-sent-event-notifications-with-html5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out 'Cramp' gem - http://cramp.in/

It's having built in support for HTML5 tehcnologies - WebSockets and SSE

Answer (score 4):

Rails 4.0 is implementing SSE, upgrading your rails and implementing SSE via rails 4.0 ActiveController::Live is probably the best option.

Otherwise you may be stuck with a less stable/performant/maintained option such as Juggernaut or other frameworks.

Source : 
http://ngauthier.com/2013/02/rails-4-sse-notify-listen.html
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#railties-notable-changes

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly HTML 5 Server Side Events but it is a tried and true method to accomplish essentially the same.  To push from the server to the client, in the past a lot of people including myself have used the Juggernaut gem (https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut - runs on top of node.js).  A little different than Server Side Events but perhaps more time tested.  The gem is still being updated it seems.

Comment: Thanks @Eskim0. The author of Juggernaut have already announced the deprecation of Juggernaut: http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/killing-a-library , and I am asking because I would like to see a standard/good approach of doing this in Rails.